# ORDER BY for different columns by passing in the column header

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I'm unsure if this is possible to be achieved, but looking to find out information regarding a JQPL query for my repository in java. I have an example table like this:

```
 Name | Address | City |
--------------------------
   A  |    A    |   C  | 
   C  |    B    |   B  |
   B  |    C    |   A  |
```

I would like it so that when I pass in the name of a column, I will be able to order by the column for the results of all rows. So for example, if I were to order by name, then it should return A B C not A C B. I know this can be achieved using basic query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Name;
```

However I'm unsure if it's possible for me to then apply that option to all columns. So if the user decided to pass in the order option to address they could do that, but also if they decided to set it to city as well. So to make it clear, I'm trying to apply the option to order by all columns for my query but unsure if that is possible. If it's not, is there an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: You can munge the query string to include the column you want for ordering.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff, sorry to ask but could you give an example to what you mean?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. But as far as ordering is concerned you can order by single or multiple columns.

Comment: Hello @RajenRaiyarela What I mean is that with my table I have three columns, it's a query connected to my repository method which is accessed by the controller. I have it now the user can pass in the column name for the controller. What I want to know, is it possible to then order by the name the user has passed in by and how can I do that?

Comment: You can append the column name received as input parameter after the order by clause in SQL statement as a variable.

Comment: Hello @RajenRaiyarela Could you provide a possible example if free please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JpaRepository` you can provide customized sorting using `Sort` parameter:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customers, Long> {

    List<Customer> findAll(Sort by);
}
```

Your service with customized sorting:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

public List<Customer> getCustomers(String ... columnNames) {
    return customerRepository.findAll(Sort.by(columnNames));
}

public List<Customer> getCustomersOrderedByNameDescAndAddress() {
    return customerRepository.findAll(Sort.by("name").descending().and(Sort.by("address")));
}
```